# Pannel applet won't spawn process

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, mate-desktop

I am using Mate, with debian8, an this has never not worked, so I'm confused now.
I have a custom applet (launcher), which reads: ssh user@ip
When clicked it does nothing, ordinarily a terminal is launched and I enter my password.

other applets work just fine. such as `mate-screenshot -a`
[image]

yes, I have ssh, the server is running, and the command works if I put it into a shell manually. 
Does the launcher keep a log some place? how might I troubleshoot this?

Comment: What's the output of `/var/log/syslog`? Launchers use `x-terminal-emulator` which is set by update-alternatives. What does `update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, just use the "connect to server" option under places menu.